# How to share a variable between classes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, oop

Here is my setup:

I have 3 classes in MATLAB.

Class 1, let's call it the "Master" class, contains an instance of each of 2 other classes, I'll just call them Class "R" and Class "S".

In my main program, I create an instance of the "Master" class, which creates an instance of "R" and "S" in its constructor. I then call a method "Run" of the "Master" class, which then starts a time based simulation which is tracked in a `timetable` object named `simdata`.

All three classes track their data over time. Right now, I'm tracking the data in three separate `simdata` properties, one in each class. The Time column data is kept in sync by passing it from the master class object to the "R" and "S" class objects.

How can I have one `simdata` property, in the "Master" class object that contains all of the data without having to pass multiple variables or entire tables or vectors back and forth between the classes over and over again?

Note that this is one example with one variable (the largest one). I currently am passing 14 variables from Master to R and from Master to S. About 5 of these are the same for all three classes and I would love to be able to reduce the count to 9 by sharing these 5 in some way.

I've tried making "Master" a superclass of "R" and "S" but that didn't work how I expect, as when I create an instance of "R" or "S" it calls the "Master" constructor. I need to create an instance of "Master" and then have its constructor create instances of "R" and "S" within the "Master" class.

I also tried it the other way around, making "R" and "S" both superclasses of "Master" - but then I can't create the `simdata` table in the "Master" class until after the "R" and "S" constructors have executed and I need it to be created before.

Does anyone have a good way of doing this? Global variables won't work as I need the table to be a property of the "Master" class.

Comment: I am not an expert here, but my feel is that you are basically using OOP wrong. The structure of your code seems just not right, if you need copies of everything here and there. `simdata` should not be a property of the class, a class is somethign that describes itself and acts in a certain way.  `simdata` should be its own class/object, and Master, S and R should just get views of this data object, not contain a copy. I think you are overdoing the OOP.

Comment: Simdata is data that describes the Master class object. The first few columns describe data unique to it, then the other columns describe properties unique to S and R, respectively. That being said, I'm not opposed to making simdata it's own object. If I do, how do I get said "views" of the object without repeatedly passing it as a parameter between my other class objects?

Comment: Why do you need a class if all you do is call its `Run` method? Make it a function! Keep your code simple!

Comment: Shared data can be implemented using a handle class object.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `Run` will not be the only method for this object. There are many more functions to make. That is the first one, it's as far as I am right now in creating it. I am starting as simple as I can to make it "go" then I will be adding to it to get more details. I want to set up all the classes now, in the beginning, so changing it later will be easier. Thank you for the suggestion on handle class objects, I will look into it.

Comment: FYI: I rethought this out and instead I did not use any superclasses or share the entire timetable as global. I simply created instances of the objects inside the master object and rather than have the data inside of the lower level objects, I just created & stored the variable NAMES in those objects and when I create my `TimeTable` object in the master object, it creates the columns based on the names passed from the sub objects and uses the associated sub object non-time dependent variables in the calculation of the respective column of the time tables inside the master object.